# Stance on joke answers to puzzles?

Tags: discussion

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454):

I was wondering what the stance on similar joke answers on Puzzling.SE?

One scenario I have in my mind, for example, would be riddles with cryptic clues that may have an outrageous, convoluted but obviously unintended solution.

Comment: Not sure if it's a dupe, but related at least: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1334/the-oracle-was-lying-just-stab-them-instead-and-other-creatively-unh and http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/answers-not-in-the-spirit-of-the-question

Comment: Most of those examples in your links were cliche and unhelpful, and clearly should be downvoted. With regards to the link I posted, the answer does not disregard the boundaries set by the question, but obviously is a joke answer nonetheless (it devoted most of its energy exaggerating the point for humor). Yet some people may still think this is rep-whoring: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17479 However, Puzzling.SE does not seem to be strictly an FAQ site, so I wonder if such boundaries still apply?

Comment: Do you have an example of such an answer? I'm not sure I've ever come across one that _also_ counts as [a well-explained answer](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/should-we-aggressively-delete-answers-that-contain-no-explanation).

Comment: Does [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16944/crack-this-code/16962#16962) count?

Comment: @f'' Yes, that does count in my book. Another example would be the original link I was reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454